# How to reload directive applying on ng-repeat div structure changes?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am implementing the following behaviour :

- Repeat div using ng-repeat
- Call a directive on that div to custom the background of that div.

It works well by combining angular with jquery.

But, when i delete an item of the repeated structure, i want to update the background as well!

Would you know how to call the directive when the repeated div changes?

An extract of the code :

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objectCollection">
    <div my-directive style="background-image='url(url-held-by-the-object)'">
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it a link option to add to the directive, a watcher to set up, a service to instantiate?

Comment: Correction done in this post. Hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: @JoshSpears that is neither valid html nor valid angular syntax

Comment: I'll give the code when it works! Do you have any experience on the angularjs mecanism to implement the "directive updating as a ng-repeat" behaviour?

Comment: If your trying to affect the styling of that current `<div>` using internal styling, then you need to use the correct syntax. Ex: `style="background-image: url(url-held-by-the-object)"` Make sure you wrap the background URL in parenthesis.  @charlietfl

Answer (score 1):

The solution i applied :

- When the document is ready, get the picture parameters for each ng-repeated element.
- Draw the picture and reference it to the model connected to the ng-repeat

Easier than i seems... thanks angular!